# Convert a text file to a dataframe, mapping different values to different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have around 90 text files to be converted to 90 excel files. The format of all the text files are as below,

> HF8 90 156 HYDE,CAROLYN 001306604 28/11/16 2,637.96 QAMAR,ATIF 004379749 17/10/16 3,202.42 ============= DEPARTMENT 156 TOTALS - 87,077.64 747 WEITHERS,MONIQUE 002790236 30/05/16 2,213.13 TANEGA,MICHELLE 002984474 25/01/16 2,003.56 HF8 90 861 ISTEL,KARIN 008794117 08/02/16 1,422.36 AGUILERA,MARIA 008794455 08/02/16 1,752.16

I wanted to convert them to Excel in the following format,

```
|---|--|---|----------------|---------|--------|---------|
|SL |NO|DEP|NAME            |ID       |DATE    |SALES    |
|---|--|---|----------------|---------|--------|---------|
|HF8|90|156|HYDE,CAROLYN    |001306604|28/11/16|2,637.96 |
|   |  |   |QAMAR,ATIF      |004379749|17/10/16|3,202.42 |
|   |  |   |                |         |        |=========|
|   |  |   |                |         |TOTALS  |87,077.64|
|   |  |747|WEITHERS,MONIQUE|002790236|30/05/16|2,213.13 |
|   |  |   |TANEGA,MICHELLE |002984474|25/01/16|2,003.56 |
|HF8|90|861|ISTEL,KARIN     |008794117|08/02/16|1,422.36 |
|   |  |   |AGUILERA,MARIA  |008794455|08/02/16|1,752.16 |
|---|--|---|----------------|---------|--------|---------|
```

Comment: I would probably say you CANNOT as you don't have a specific order for the data, as it is hard for humans to figure out I would say you cannot make a machine to answer that, if you have any other details please update the question.

Comment: Have edited, by adding the column names. The data have to be delimited by a space and put into their respective columns.

Comment: Eg: "HF8|90|156|HYDE,CAROLYN|001306604|28/11/16|2,637.96" should be the first row,
"QAMAR,ATIF|004379749|17/10/16|3,202.42" but the second row should start from the name column

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be done, although it requires substantial fluency in regex.
It is more convenient to divide this task into the following steps.

## Step 1: Read the input file

Read the input file as a **fixed width file**, into a **single** column:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('Input.txt', widths=[100], names=['line'])
```

For your data, the result is:

```
                                                line
0  HF8 90 156 HYDE,CAROLYN 001306604 28/11/16 2,6...
1             QAMAR,ATIF 004379749 17/10/16 3,202.42
2                                          =========
3                  DEPARTMENT 156 TOTALS - 87,077.64
4   747 WEITHERS,MONIQUE 002790236 30/05/16 2,213.13
5        TANEGA,MICHELLE 002984474 25/01/16 2,003.56
6  HF8 90 861 ISTEL,KARIN 008794117 08/02/16 1,42...
7         AGUILERA,MARIA 008794455 08/02/16 1,752.16
```

Don't worry about "shortened" lines, it is only the presentation detail of
*Pandas*. The actual content of each row is as it should be.

## Step 2: Extract *ID*, *DATE* and *SALES* columns

Run:

```
pat1 = '''
(?P<Init>.*?)
(?P<ID>\d+)?\s?
(?:DEPARTMENT\s\d+\s)?(?P<DATE>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|TOTALS)?(?:\s-)?\s*
(?P<SALES>[\d,]+\.\d{2}|=+)'''
df1 = df.line.str.extract(pat1, flags=re.X).fillna('')
```

Named capturing groups provide proper column names.
For code readability, I used a regex with *X* (extended) regex flag,
so you have to *import re*.

The result is that we get 3 "last" columns and *Init* column - the
"initial" part of each row:

```
                       Init         ID      DATE      SALES
0  HF8 90 156 HYDE,CAROLYN   001306604  28/11/16   2,637.96
1               QAMAR,ATIF   004379749  17/10/16   3,202.42
2                                                 =========
3                                         TOTALS  87,077.64
4     747 WEITHERS,MONIQUE   002790236  30/05/16   2,213.13
5          TANEGA,MICHELLE   002984474  25/01/16   2,003.56
6   HF8 90 861 ISTEL,KARIN   008794117  08/02/16   1,422.36
7           AGUILERA,MARIA   008794455  08/02/16   1,752.16
```

## Step 3: Extract 4 "initial" columns

Run:

```
pat2 = '''
(?P<SL>[A-Z]+\d+)?\s?
(?P<NO>\d{2})?\s?
(?P<DEP>\d{3})?\s?
(?P<NAME>[A-Z,]+)'''
df2 = df1.Init.str.extract(pat2, flags=re.X).fillna('')
```

The result is:

```
    SL  NO  DEP              NAME
0  HF8  90  156      HYDE,CAROLYN
1                      QAMAR,ATIF
2                                
3                                
4           747  WEITHERS,MONIQUE
5                 TANEGA,MICHELLE
6  HF8  90  861       ISTEL,KARIN
7                  AGUILERA,MARIA
```

## Step 4: Concatenate results of step 2 and 3

Run:

```
pd.concat([df2, df1.iloc[:, 1:]], axis=1)
```

The (final) result is:

```
    SL  NO  DEP              NAME         ID      DATE      SALES
0  HF8  90  156      HYDE,CAROLYN  001306604  28/11/16   2,637.96
1                      QAMAR,ATIF  004379749  17/10/16   3,202.42
2                                                       =========
3                                               TOTALS  87,077.64
4           747  WEITHERS,MONIQUE  002790236  30/05/16   2,213.13
5                 TANEGA,MICHELLE  002984474  25/01/16   2,003.56
6  HF8  90  861       ISTEL,KARIN  008794117  08/02/16   1,422.36
7                  AGUILERA,MARIA  008794455  08/02/16   1,752.16
```

## Final remarks

Note that both *DATE* and *SALES* column are stored as **strings**.
Theoretically they should be converted into dates and numbers,
but the problem is that some rows have data in different format.
It is a side effect of inserting presentation details into some columns.
E.g. *TOTAL* is by no means any *Date*.
The same pertains to a sequence of "=" instead of the *SALES* value.